# IntelliJ Idea not able to recognize some Cucumber Steps

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I was trying to develop a module using BDD i.e. using Cucumber. This is the first time that I am trying this. I have defined two Scenarios in my Feature and using IntelliJ itself, I have created Steps for both the scenarios in a particular file.

However, on running the tests, the runner cannot find steps defined for the second scenario, even though they are in the same file as the steps for the first scenario.

The steps for the first scenario execute without any issues.

===EDIT====

Just to reiterate, the config under which the tests are running has the glue defined which identifies the steps for the first scenario, so it should be able to do the same for the second scenario as well, but doesn't. I have restarted the IDE, but to no avail.

===EDIT 2====

Ok, So now none of the steps are being recognized. Even the steps defined for First scenario are not being found by the runner.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that:

- Cucumber for java plugin is installed and compatible with your intellij idea version
- *\src\main\resources* is marked as `Resources Root`
- *\src\main\resources* contains the files *.feature*
- *\src\main\java* is marked as `Sources Root`
- *\src\main\java* contain the folder *step_definitions*
- The `Feature` configuration in the run test class contain `step_definitions` as `Glue`
- The code is building

After those checks the steps should be recognized.

Comment: Do you have any links to explain why the feature or step definitions file must be marked as described? Very helpful, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps will help in 90% cases:

1. Install Cucumber plugin for Java and(or) groovy
2. Mark feature folder as test resources root and steps folder as test sources root

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but check if your scenarios description have dots(.) in them, if you see just remove those dots(.) and check. Like

```
Scenario: Some determinable business situation.
```

to

```
 Scenario: Some determinable business situation
```